# Using Repository in edit method Repository is null

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

With laravel 7 /livewire app I make crud using Repository and I got listing of data ok,
In mount event I assign protected var $FacilityRepository , which works ok in render method,

but it is null in edit method and I got error:

```
Call to a member function getById() on null
```

when user clicks on “edit link”

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\library\CheckValueType;
use App\Settings;
use DB;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Facility;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\FacilityRepositoryInterface;


class Facilities extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $form= [
        'name'=>'',
        'descr'=> '',
        'created_at'=> '',
        'is_reopen'       => false,
    ];

    public $current_facility_id;
    public $filter_name= '';
    public $updateMode = 'browse';

    protected $FacilityRepository;
    public function render()
    {
        $this->facility_rows_count = Facility
            ::getByName($this->filter_name, true)
            ->count();
        $backend_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_per_page', CheckValueType::cvtInteger, 20);
        \Log::info( 'render -10 $this->FacilityRepository::' . print_r(  json_encode($this->FacilityRepository), true  ) );
        // line above logged as : [2020-09-04 16:46:26] local.INFO: render -10 $this->FacilityRepository::{}

        return view('livewire.admin.facilities.container', [
            'facilityDataRows' => $this->FacilityRepository->filterWithPagination(
                [
                    'name'=>$this->filter_name,
                ],
                $backend_per_page
            ),
            'facility_rows_count'=> $this->facility_rows_count
        ]); // this listing is rendered OK
    }


    public function mount(  FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository  ) {
        $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
        \Log::info( '-101mount $this->FacilityRepository::' . print_r(  json_encode($this->FacilityRepository), true  ) );
        // line above logged as : [2020-09-04 16:46:26] local.INFO: -101mount $this->FacilityRepository::{}
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        \Log::info( '-1 edit $id::' . print_r(  json_encode( $id ), true  ) );
        \Log::info( '-1 edit $this->FacilityRepository::' . print_r( $this->FacilityRepository, true  ) );
        // line above logged as : [2020-09-04 16:46:28] local.INFO: -1 edit $this->FacilityRepository::
        // AND ERROR NEXT
        $this->form = $this->FacilityRepository->getById($id)->toArray();
        \Log::info( '-1023 $this->form ::' . print_r(  json_encode( $this->form ), true  ) );


        $this->current_facility_id = $id;
        $this->form['created_at'] = getCFFormattedDateTime($this->form['created_at']);
        $this->emit('facility_opened',[ 'mode'=>'edit', 'id'=>$id ]);
        $this->updateMode = 'edit';
    }
```

In template edit link is defined as :

```
@foreach($facilityDataRows as $nextFacilityDataRow)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right m-0">
            <a wire:click="edit({{$nextFacilityDataRow->id}})"
                class="p-1 a_edit_item_{{$nextFacilityDataRow->id}} a_link">
                {{$nextFacilityDataRow->id}}
            </a>
        </td>

...
```

Why error and how to fix it ?

**Modified # 2:**

1. If I make

   class Facilities extends Component
   {
   ...
   public $FacilityRepository;
   }

I got error :

```
Livewire component's [admin.facilities] public property [FacilityRepository] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.
```

2. I tried to declare method edit as :

   public function edit( FacilityRepositoryInterface $facilityRepository, int $id)
   { // Did you mean this ?
   ...
   }

I got error :

```
Call to a member function filterWithPagination() on null
```

on method filterWithPagination, which is used in render method, when I show listing of data.
Which way is correct ?

**Modified # 3:**
If to modify :

```
public function render(FacilityRepositoryInterface $facilityRepository)
{
```

I got error :

```
Declaration of App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Facilities::render(App\Repositories\Interfaces\FacilityRepositoryInterface $facilityRepository) should be compatible with Livewire\Component::render()
```

?

**Modified # 4:**
Opening page in mode I have 2 inputs with lazy defined, like

```
            <dd class="horiz_divider_right_23" wire:model="form.title.lazy" x-data="{ name: '{{$form['name']}}'}">
                
                <input
                    x-model="name"
                    x-on:blur="$dispatch('name', name)"
                    id="name"
                    class="form-control editable_field admin_control_input"
                    placeholder="Enter descriptive name"
                    autocomplete=off
                >
                @error('form.name')
                <div class="validation_error">{{ clearValidationError($message,['form.'=>'']) }}</div> @enderror
            </dd>
```

and when I edit some of fields on blur ervent I got the same error :

```
Call to a member function filterWithPagination() on null
```

with url in error description :

```
VM5783:1 POST http://local-hostels3.com/livewire/message/admin.facilities 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

where http://local-hostels3.com is my local hosting

Have I in some way to overrride message method ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^1.3",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> protected and private properties DO NOT persist between Livewire updates. In general, you should avoid using them for storing state.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/properties/#important-notes

That being said, you can use dependency injection again, just pass whatever you need (`FacilityRepositoryInterface` in this case) as the first argument(s) of the `edit` method.

Same applies to the `render` method, so you can skip `mount` altogether.

### Correction

The last bit in my original answer is wrong, you cannot use DI in the render method.

So for use in render, use the mount method and for use in edit, bring it via the first parameter. If render complains about not having it after usage of edit, save to the protected property inside edit as well.

Final code, that should work

```php
class Facilities extends Component
{
  protected $FacilityRepository;

  public function mount(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository)
  {
    $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
  }

  public function render()
  {
    // use $this->FacilityRepository->...
  }

  public function edit(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository, $id)
  {
    $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
    // rest of the edit method from your code
  }
}
```

Comment: And which can be decision?
Please look at Modified # 2:

Comment: The error about public properties you got was expected beviour, it's explained at the same link, I provided in above. As for the second error, in your example, that method is used in `render`. Have you updated that method as I pointed out above? Don't forget to update the call to `$facilityRepository->filterWithPagination(...)` afterwards.

Comment: Please look at Modified # 3

Comment: Okay, I guess I was wrong, sorry about that, misunderstood the docs. So, for initial render, bring in the repository via `mount` and save it to the protected property. For `edit` bring it in via first parameter.

Comment: Thanks! It helped in my case, but I got next error.
Pls look at Modified # 4.

Comment: I'm assuming this error is coming from when the lifecycle hooks trigger, but I can be wrong. I'd start another question, maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

add boot method

```
public function boot(FacilityRepositoryInterface $FacilityRepository)
{
    $this->FacilityRepository = $FacilityRepository;
}
```